# SSRS, how can I iterate over a hard-coded set

Tags: sql, loops, reporting-services, set, bids

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but here goes. Let's say I have a dataset containing some products and their prices, and I want to display a table that shows a product, its price and a "tax" column. The tax is simply some fraction multiplied by the price. Now, let's say I want to show the same table for several regions with different taxes. The region and tax information isn't available in a SQL table and must be hard-coded in the report. I could create a separate table for each region, of course, but ideally I'd like to use a group that simply repeats the same table several times, iterating over my hard-coded set.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No loops. Put the region and tax info in a table variable in your dataset. Then do a cross join with your real data.

```
declare @RegionTax table (
    Region nvarchar(10),
    Tax float
)

insert @RegionTax values ('Region 1', .05)
insert @RegionTax values ('Region 2', .06)
insert @RegionTax values ('Region 3', .07)

select
    *
from
    Products p, @RegionTax t
```

Comment: Thanks! That will work, but out of curiosity, is it possible to create temp tables without having a valid SQL data source? There is a possibility the report will use fetchXML at some point in the future, so I'm wondering if it will be possible to create temp SQL tables without having a SQL connection. I guess the question boils down to whether it's stored in memory or the actual database.

Comment: It's a SQL feature and as such requires a SQL connection. You'd need a different approach to do the same thing in XML and unfortunately I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

If the regions are in the dataset, you can add a computed column to the dataset. The computation would use some form of 'case' (can't remember the syntax - sorry!) to generate the right multiplier for the Region column and multiply the price by that.

Comment: I don't have any region or tax information in a dataset. The only data I have is a list of products and prices.